# Get all the Users from the User Profile Manager with Server Side Object Model (C#)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, user-profile, user-profile-service

I have used-

```
var srchResults = profileManager.GetEnumerator();
while (SrchResults.MoveNext()){//Code here}
```

But it takes a lot of time because the users are near about 4000 or more and I have to show them on search.
For example- If I have searched with **A** then result should show all the users whose **Last Name start with letter A**.

So what is the best practice/approach to show them within the time.
Or is there any provision to fire query on User Profile? So it will reduce the time.

**Note:** All the searched results are shown on the page without paging all are shown once.

Comment: Is it compulsory for you to do the server side code? else you can refer to the client side scripting like AngularJS + REST queries that can work more faster.

Comment: How about fetching users from search with something like "LastName:A*"?

Comment: With the Search Service, we can get the first 200 records only.
that's why I have changed to iterate with all users.

Comment: Yes, I can try this with AngularJS + REST.